# Moving to a state where my employer has no business set up - implications?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, employment, state-income-tax, moving

I am moving to Colorado, where my company (based in NY and FL) does not have an office. I will still be employed by them, but working from my home in CO.

What are the tax implications for the company? They are saying that it will be a huge tax cost for them to have just 1 employee in a state where they have no other business.

Answer (score 3):

Generally with most states and Colorado specifically, having an employee in the state triggers "nexus" or presence for your company in that state.  With nexus, your company will be subject to state income taxes and sales taxes in Colorado.

The company will have apportion the services that you render to clients as income in Colorado and pay income tax to Colorado on it.